# How to pass variable in value field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
var x = data[1];
cell1.innerHTML ='<input id="text" type="text" value= "'x'"/>' ;
```

The code displays nothing when passing the variable but something written as value = "h"; will display h in the textbox

Comment: Why adding PHP tag here for javascript question?

Comment: Did you look at the developer console? I am sure there is a nice error message sitting there waiting for you to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use + to concatenate value into tag:

```
var x = data[1];
cell1.innerHTML ='<input id="text" type="text" value= "'+x+'"/>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it good.

```
cell1.innerHTML ='<input id="text" type="text" value= "'+x+'"/>' ;
```

Notice the plus signs